# Accessing XML/PHP with period in tag

Tags: php, xml, traversal

Quick newbie question here, how do I access `totalResults`?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <opensearch:totalResults>1</opensearch:totalResults>
  <posts>
    <post>
      <score>10</score>
    </post>
  </posts>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

To access the `score` I would do this:

**PHP**

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($theXMLabove);
echo $xmlObj->posts->post[0]->score;
```

But none of these work for the `totalResults`:

```
echo $xmlObj->opensearch:totalResults;
echo $xmlObj->opensearch->totalResults;
```

Sorry for asking such a lame question...

Documentation on how to traverse XML with PHP is also appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: The `opensearch` namespace isn't defined in that document.

Comment: Oops, I've added the namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the namespace added you can do this:

```
$opensearch = $xmlObj->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/');
echo $opensearch->totalResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `$xmlObj->children('opensearch');`

Im not sure if that will work though because from what you posted the `opensearch` namespace isnt defined as an `xmlns`. That might not make a difference though - im not sure because when ive had to deal with ns in simplexml the ns has always been explicitly defined.

Comment: Since the namespace wasn't specified in the first place, this wasn't a well-formed XML document to begin with.  Once the namespace is defined, though, the solution provided by thetaiko is the most appropriate.